# Does autocomplete of interface for C++ exist in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm using `Microsoft IntelliSence C/C++` extension and looking for a way to autocomplete interface (paste pure virt. methods empty bodies of base classes) using some shortcut.
Any ideas how to achive that?

Comment: Clangd does that.